# How to correct Nested routing in angular 7?

Tags: angular

Can somebody tell me how correct to set up routing when using multiple modules in my project? I have app.module and administration.module with its  under module gestion-profil.module some components declared in.I want to know how to connect modules and edit properly routing in administration.module.This is the architecture of my project:

[image]

and this my  code :

app.routing.module.ts:

```
  {
    path: 'M_DROIT_USER',
    loadChildren:'./features/administration-module/administration-module.module#AdministrationModule'
  }
   ];


@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

gestion-administration-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GestionprofilComponent } from './gestion- 
profile/Components/gestionprofil/gestionprofil.component';
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  children: [{
   loadChildren:'./features/administration-module/gestion-profile/gestion- 
 profile.module#GestionProfileModule'}]
}
 ];
@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  declarations: [GestionprofilComponent ],
 exports: [RouterModule]
  })
 export class GestionAdministrationRoutingModule { }
```

administration-module.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GestionProfileModule } from './gestion-profile/gestion-profile.module';
import { GestionprofilComponent } from './gestion- 
profile/Components/gestionprofil/gestionprofil.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [ ],
 imports: [
  CommonModule
  ]
 })
 export class AdministrationModule { }
```

gestion-profile.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { GestionprofilComponent } from './Components/gestionprofil/gestionprofil.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [GestionprofilComponent],
 imports: [
CommonModule,
 ]
  })
 export class GestionProfileModule { }
```

gestion-profil-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GestionprofilComponent } from './Components/gestionprofil/gestionprofil.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  component: GestionprofilComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
 }
 ,
 {
  path: 'M_DROIT_GRP',
  component: GestionprofilComponent,
 },
];
@NgModule({
 declarations: [],
imports: [
  RouterModule.forChild(routes)
 ]
})
export class GestionProfilRoutingModule { }
```

how to resolve nested routin in angular 7?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. You have nested modules and are using lazy loading for the modules. What's the problem?

Comment: @Viqas it's not working

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: yes this is the error: main.ts:12 Error: Invalid configuration of route '': routes must have either a path or a matcher specified
    at validateNode (router.js:610)
    at validateConfig (router.js:577)
    at validateNode (router.js:623)
    at validateConfig (router.js:577)
    at Router.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.Router.resetConfig (router.js:4108)
    at new Router (router.js:3784)
    at setupRouter (router.js:5581)
    at _callFactory (core.js:21292)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:21238)
    at initNgModule (core.js:21168)

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks to be with your `gestion-administration-routing.module.ts` file. Change the routes to the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './features/administration-module/gestion-profile/gestion- profile.module#GestionProfileModule'
    }
```

The compiler is complaining that you don't have a either `loadChildren` or a component for the path.